# Spaces in folder names

Tags: robots.txt

I am a bit new at search engine optimisation, and I am just trying to write a robot.txt file.  I want to disallow pages in the terms and conditions folder, which has a space in it.

Should I write:

```
Disallow: /Page TermsAndConditions/
```

Or:

```
Disallow: /Page%20TermsAndConditions/
```

Or both, or does it not matter?

(I want to disallow this folder because this is full of technical jargon that *I think* is messing up the content keywords found by the googlebot - or do I have this wrong as well?).

---

Edit:

I found this page from googe [Robots.txt Specifications](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt).  Which says: "Non-7-bit ASCII characters in a path may be included as UTF-8 characters or as percent-escaped UTF-8 encoded characters per RFC 3986".  So I guess the answer to this question is that it doesn't matter.

Comment: It would be nice if people who down vote a question would leave a comment to say why.  If you want me to contribute to SO in a positive way then you need to tell me, in a nice way, what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the folder without a space and avoid the issue.

```
Disallow: /PageTermsAndConditions/
```

Comment: Since I got no answers in 8 hours I implemented this solution. I don't feel that this is an answer to the question that I posted, but it is more of a work around. Since it involved a lot more work - going through the code, recompiling, runing tests and re-publishing the website. Since then I have now discovered what appears to be an answer (see my edit in the question).